# Connection failing with pop3 using java mail api to Exchange server

Tags: api, email, ssl, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am facing issue, connecting clients Exchange server via JAVAMAIL api using pop3. It works fine with gmail. Please look into this, if is something familiar.

Following exception we get while trying to connect on client's Exchange server

```
  javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connecti
on?
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:210)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at TestPOP3Connection.run(TestPOP3Connection.java:23)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext conne
ction?
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown
Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Un
known Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Sou
rce)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Sou
rce)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java
:507)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:107)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:261)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:206)
... 2 more
```

Thanks in advance
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect using SSL, but you're connecting to a port that doesn't support SSL.

Gmail requires SSL, so your program is probably set up to do that, but then when changing to use your Exchange server you probably changed the host name and set the port number to 110.  The SSL port number for POP3 is 995.  Of course, make sure your Exchange server is configured to accept SSL requests on that port.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer...this problem is resolved. We removed SSL properties that we were setting in system properties, Its getting connected but not fetching mail via pop3...